# docker container stops unexpectedly

Tags: nginx, docker, dockerfile

I have a docker container which stops unexpectedly.

The important part of my docker image looks like this:

```
...
ENTRYPOINT ["./start.sh"]

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

It's al executed pending the build. Than I start the container with `docker run -p 80:8080 myimage:latest`

I see something like this when I perform `docker ps`

```
"./start.sh nginx -g "
```

But a few seconds later the container stops (instead of keeping running nginx)

`docker logs` show me the logs of the output of my `start.sh`
The last command in that .sh is an echo of "fine" and I see that.

What I want to obtain is that the container executes the entrypointscript and after that it executes the nginx server.

Comment: Please include your start.sh script.

Comment: As the other comment says, we need to see your start script, but I have a feeling you've misunderstood the role of the ENTRYPOINT and COMMAND.  You should review the details of these at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ENTRYPOINT and CMD does not run them both consecutively.    The CMD arguments are appended to the entrypoint.  Your docker ps shows this exactly.   [This](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/dockerfile-entrypoint-vs-cmd/) is a decent explanation.

You need to make your start.sh handle your CMD arguments, or have your start.sh call nginx, or rework it alltogether.